# Как изменять ImageView в Android studio по названию файла

Tags: android, imageview

Есть программа. Надо чтобы при чтении строки программа показывала определенную картинку

тоесть если:

```
String img = "orangejuice"
```

то программа сделает следующее:

```
ImageView tvImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
tvImage.setImageResourse("R.drawable." + img)
```

Это, логично, не сработает. Как мне доработать строчку `tvImage.setImageResourse("R.drawable." + img)`
чтобы сработало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
String img = "orangejuice";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(img , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: не работает. Я уже видел это на Stackoverflow. Точнее не работает . "getResources()". Не может найти это

Comment: Ааа. в моем случае нужно v.getResources()...